# SQL Reporting Services Express: datasource to external server

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS 2008 **Express** Edition, is it possible to create a datasource that connects to an external SQL server, or is it artificially limited to same SQL Server and instance of that   Reporting Services engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out myself. You can not define an external datasource.

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a linked server, where you would just call the procedures in the remote (linked) data source.

Comment: That doesn't work because you cannot add the linked server into the initial catalog in the connection string. Otherwise, you have to add all your stored procedures to a server on the local database, and then you have to hard-code the linked server calls there, which is possible in theory, but you can count on the fact that in practice, you will never ever have the time to sync all procedures in those two databases, and neither is it a good idea even when you have the time. And even that assumes that ALL your report's datasets use stored procedures, which is extremely unlikely.